# Mount a single vmdk to multiple physical computers (NOT VM's)

Tags: mount, vmdk

Is there any way that I can mount a single `.vmdk` file to multiple physical computers as a storage drive?

I tried to but it seems that the `.vmdk` locks after mounting it to a single computer so it won't be mounted to others. Is there any way around this?

I am trying to install a game that installs a Windows service to be able to run. I have 50 computers that must run this game at the same time. I tried installing the game to my network storage but the service won't start because it requires a local installation.

I have a server PC with an Intel i5 CPU, 8GB RAM and 4x1TB RAID 10 disks.

Answer (score 1):

That is not possible. A .vmdk or any disk image cannot be shareable unless it is a read-only media. I don't know if there is a read-only mount mode for .vmdk available anyway.

The reason for this is that if it were shared and any computer would write on it, other computers would have no idea that a write had occurred, and the computers' view on hard disk contents would be different, causing the contents to be corrupt.

Answer (score 1):

It is theoretically possible, there are filesystems that support concurrent access to the underlying block device. NTFS isn't one of them, naturally.

Your problem lies elsewhere, though: Even if you were to install this program to a (non-OS) hard drive and copy the contents to all PCs, they wouldn't have the service installed.

If you need a network drive that looks local, use iSCSI. It's vastly superior in performance than mounting a filesystem that is on a virtual disk that is on a network filesystem that is backed by a remote filesystem... ;)

Answer (score 0):

Just a creative suggestion here, but since you're using a "server PC" (I'm assuming it's Windows), you might want to try converting the VMDK into a VHD.  VHD is a Microsoft virtual disk format.  Here is a nice [tutorial](http://www.petri.co.il/converting-vmware-files.htm) and free product that allows you to convert between VMDK and VHD.  Once you have it in VHD format I'd be curious to see whether or not you're able to mount it to multiple physical computers.  Sorry I don't know for sure, but I thought it might be worth suggesting.  Good luck!